# Tableau + Okta: Signout not enabled for SAML users

Tags: saml, okta, tableau-api

We have configured our tableau online site to be authenticated by OKta. This has been working for us. But I don't see an option to sign out.

When I look at the authentication section in tableau online I see the message "IdP is not configured to support SAML single logout (SLO)"

Is there a way to enable this?

Answer (score 0):

Okta does support Single Logout within the General settings of the SAML Application.

[image]

At the bottom of this screenshot, you can see that SAML Single Logout is disabled, if you edit the SAML Settings and enable that, You will be given the options to deal with the Single Logout.

[image]

You can also refer to this answer for more details. [SAML Single logout through OKTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033237/saml-single-logout-through-okta)

Comment: Strange! I don't have the 'SAML Settings' section under the Tableau online app in Okta. I just have 'App Settings', 'VPN Notification', 'App Embed Link'